# Как в OpenGL залить буфер определенным значением?

Tags: opengl

Допустим у меня Deferred Render. Для него создается несколько промежуточных буферов (цвета, нормали, позиции и т.п.). К примеру есть `GL_FRAMEBUFFER` который отвечает за значения позиции в пикселе (RGB <-> XYZ). Как мне установить определенное значение для всех пикселей, например `0, 0, -1000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее, нужно выбрать буфер, выбрать цвет (значения) и выполнить заливку:

```
glBindFrameBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Handle);
glClearColor(R, G, B, A); // 0, 0, -1000, 0
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```